# Convert allocating/deallocating multidimensional arrays from C++ to C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

I have a C++ code...

```
// global
DWORD* P;
DWORD (*S)[256];

// then later allocate memory
P = new DWORD[18];
S = new DWORD[4][256];

// later on, free memory
delete P;
delete [] S;
```

that I want to convert to C. I tried ..

```
/* global */
DWORD* P;
DWORD (*S)[256];

/* allocate */
P = malloc(sizeof(DWORD[18]));
S = malloc(sizeof(DWORD[4][256]));

/* free */
free(P);
free(S);
```

It works and I don't get any errors or warnings from the compiler (GCC) but I'm not sure if this is the right way, and I'm guessing it leaks memory, probably in freeing the multidimensional array.

Also, are those arrays too big to allocate on the stack? Can I do it like this instead and forget about malloc/free?

```
DWORD P[18] = {0};
DWORD S[4][256] = {{0}};
```

Comment: `delete P` is wrong, should be `delete[] P`.

Comment: Other than the wrong `delete` already mentioned, I don't see any issue with what you are doing, although I would prefer to write `S = malloc(4 * sizeof(DWORD[256]));`.

Comment: @interjay Thanks. @jxh So `free(S);` frees it correctly?

Comment: To reap the dynamically allocated memory, call `free()` on the pointer returned by `malloc()` (or its cousins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is perfectly safe. `malloc()` and `free()` are only concerned with allocating a number of bytes from the heap. This is why you use `sizeof()` inside the call to `malloc()`, to determine the number of bytes that datatype needs. You could also, for example, do `S = malloc(sizeof(DWORD) * 4 * 256)` and get the same result.

To answer the second half of your question, neither of those arrays are even close to being too big for the stack. You could stack-allocate those in either C or C++.